# Windows TCP timeout

Tags: windows-xp, tcp, timeout

Is there on windows any default timeout for tcp connection? So when no answere is received the connection would be closed.
Why im asking is that on one machine the connection is closed afther 5 minutes.(Windows XP) Running the same client - server connection on other machine the connection is kept open forever like it should be.
Or maybe there is some global java virtual machine setting somewhere i should know about?

The server and client run on the same local machine

Answer (score 1):

How about this? It's the same sort of thing you are asking:

https://serverfault.com/questions/193160/which-is-the-default-tcp-connect-timeout-in-windows

Comment: Yes, i have seen this, but this is not really what im looking for.

Comment: How else would you change the default TCP settings? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739819(WS.10).aspx hmmm, when the device (nic) iself has settings it is using as seen in the nics own "advanced" device settings? Could it be that the 2 different machines use 2 different Nic devices ? I do NOT see anything in my advanced device settings to think that. How about the machine actually putting the nic to Sleep? going to sleep?

Comment: How about the paramter things for Half Open connections? https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=half+open+connections+xp&pbx=1&oq=half+open+connection&aq=1&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=0l0l1l125l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=756fe63c7c87b84&biw=1736&bih=807  I am just trying to remember if there is anything else, the Last thing I would want is for a connection to stay open, but that IS what you want.

Comment: Just for info: The server and client run on the same local machine.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the two clients actually don't behave identically.  If you really want to know what is going on, you'll need a diagnostics tool like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), which is pretty straight forward.